# Is it possible to enumerate commits in git log?

Tags: git, git-log

I frequently need to [`squash`](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) many small commits into a big one to merge from a development feature branch into the `master`.  So I do

```
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Where X is the number of the latest commits to squash.  However, as I am sometimes dealing with literally dozens of commits, I must count them manually in `git log`, which I am trying to avoid.

Is there a way to produce a git log-like report that will, in addition to showing commit SHAs, also enumerate them 0-n ?

Comment: Are you sure `git merge --squash` wouldn't work?

Comment: where did i ever mention that ?

Comment: You didn't, hence why I am asking if you considered it.  If you are squashing all it is the easiest by far.  If you are squashing a few, then the `git reset --soft SHA` trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do

```
git rebase -i <sha>
```

(where `<sha>` is the parent of the last commit to be rebased)

or

```
git rebase -i <sha>~
```

(where `<sha>` is the last commit to be rebased).

---

Back to your original question, I don’t think there is a way to do this. Because SHA’s are the first-class citizens in the git world, and the `^` and `~` syntax is used exactly to go back a small known number of commits. It just doesn’t make any sense to use this syntax when you don’t know the number of steps to go back in advance. And as a result I don’t think `git log` has any means of enumerating commits simply because I can’t think of any use-cases for it; one can always use SHA.

That said, of course no one can stop you from doing `git log --pretty=oneline` and numbering the lines using any external tool (thanks, Unix), e.g. `awk`, `nl` or whatever you like.

Comment: is `<sha>` the oldest commit to go back to ?

Comment: @amphibient It’s the parent of the last commit to be rebased. You can also use `git rebase -i <sha>~`.

Comment: @amphibient I also added some thoughts on why I bet `git log` doesn’t have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h" @{3}..| nl -v0
 0  da15a22
 1  64e0e39
 2  33fa834
```

and replace `3` with desired number of commits since `HEAD`.

Comment: I didn't realize you want the commit index number. I updated the answer.

Comment: Perhaps not what the OP was asking, but a helpful answer! Here is a variant of this answer that numerically counts each commit in by date: 

git log --pretty=format:"[%ad] %h%d %an %s (dim)"|sort |nl